# Change the cardinallity ratio of a an already existing field from 1 to unlimited

Tags: 8, webforms

I've created a webform with a text field which has cardinality of 1 and there are submissions made for that webform. I now want to change the cardinality to unlimited, but I can't do it in the webform UI. I'm not able to change the value.

This is the tootltip shown when I hover over the *Allowed number of values* field in webform form element settings Allowed number of values field.

> There is data for this element in the database. This setting can no longer be changed.

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

I tried to programmatically change it using `hook_form_alter()`.

```php
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'form_id') {
    $form['field_name']['cardinality']['#default_value'] = FIELD_CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED;
  }
}
```

That didn't work either. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to change an element with a singular cardinality via the YAML source without any data loss. You would definitely lose data going from multiple cardinality to singular.

In the YAML source, add the `'#multiple': true` property to the element.

```
name:
  '#type': textfield
  '#title': 'Name'
  '#multiple': true
```